# C# Windows Form Application, I want things to move along with the window when I resize it

Tags: c#, winforms

I want all these things (the ones in the red circle) to move along with the window when I resize it. I tried *Anchor* but things are just stretching, not moving. Is there any easy way to do this?

[image]

Thank you in advance, this is my first question on this site, but you have helped me many times before.

Comment: I think Anchor is the way to go. But you do need to make sure you apply the anchor correctly. Which anchor settings have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Anchor` to `Top,Right`

OR

Set `Anchor` to `Right`

It should work

Comment: Thank you, @jhyap, I set 'Anchor' to 'Left, Right', that was my mistake. Sorry, I don't have enough "reputation" to upvote your answer.

Comment: come back for upvote when you have enough reputation :) have a nice day